# Find the sum of the radii of inscribed and circumscribed circles for an n-sided in terms of cot

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The sum of the radii of inscribed and circumscribed circles for an n-sided regular polygon of side 'a', is

(a) $ a.cot(\frac{\pi}{n}) $

(b) $ \frac{a}{2}cot(\frac{\pi}{2n}) $

(c) $ a.cot(\frac{\pi}{2n}) $

(d) $ \frac{a}{4}cot(\frac{\pi}{2n}) $

I have partially solved this problem. I found the radii of the two circle individually but could not find the sum in terms of cot.

[image]

$$ \theta=\frac{180}{n} $$
$$ cot\theta=\frac{r}{\frac{a}{2}} $$
$$ r = cot\theta.\frac{a}{2} $$
$$ sin\theta = \frac{\frac{a}{2}}{R} $$
$$ R = cosec\theta.\frac{a}{2}$$
$$ r+R = \frac{a}{2}.(cosec(\frac{180}{n}) + cot(\frac{180}{n}))$$

But the final answer is not in terms of cot, does anyone know how to express the entire thing in terms of cot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Pythagorean identity to replace cosecant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\csc2A+\cot2A=\dfrac{1+\cos2A}{\sin2A}=\dfrac{2\cos^2A}{2\cos A\sin A}=\cot A$$

Can you recognize $A$ here?

Answer (score 0):

Or else we can directly match it for a square as a polygon, 
But only if it is asked in question to solve quickly